# C# tcp socket server client connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

really need you help .

my project is to connect two PC's via cable and use the tcp socket send the string in the client text box form to the server. the problem is thati can just send one string then the connection will close.

client code(c#):of course in the try catch way :

```
       String str = textBox2.Text;
       Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
 textBox1.Text="Sending...";

 stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

  byte[] bb = new byte[100];
  int k = stm.Read(bb,0,100);

 for (int i = 0;i < k; i++)
 {
  Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
  }


    tcpclnt.Close();

 //////////////
```

the server code :also in the try catch way :

```
   int k = 0;
   byte[] b = new byte[100];
   for (; ; )
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       { }
           k = s.Receive(b);
       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
       textBox1.Text = "Recieved...";

       for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
       {
           textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
       }
       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
       ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
       s.Send(asen.GetBytes("Automatic message:" + "String received by server!"));
       textBox1.Text = "\n Automatic message sent!";


       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
     s.Close();
       }
```

my question is : can i make a loop in the server to send not just one string ,i need to send many string  without close the connection .?

note : the client and server every one will be executed after the button in each form pressed.

note : the connection on some port will be establish and succeed in the form load .

Comment: Yes, you can make a loop and send as much as you want. You don't need to close the socket until you're done.

Comment: i don't know how , i make a loop in the server  , but the 
 k=s.recieve(b) will stuck it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, move the close out of the for loop

```
   int k = 0;
   byte[] b = new byte[100];
   for (; ; )
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       { }
       k = s.Receive(b);
       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
       textBox1.Text = "Recieved...";

       for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
       {
           textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
       }
       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
       ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
       s.Send(asen.GetBytes("Automatic message:" + "String received by server!"));
       textBox1.Text = "\n Automatic message sent!";


       MessageBox.Show(k + "");
     }
     s.Close();
```

Comment: i did it 1 million time , the same . look what is the message that back to the client from the server  :
|
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: Maybe you can show us the whole code, as the client and server both close the socket after send/receiving once

Comment: the problem in the client side < the tcpclnt.close () will abort the connection . but how to fix it . if i move it to close connection button , the server will accept onceafter thebutton is pressed . so how to deal with it

Comment: @Khalid jarrah, why loop for 100,000 times ? Why not an endless loop ? There are posts on SO with good code for an async sockets; event based is also a good way to go. Also, is your code in a button's click event handler ? If so, move the stm to the form's scope not the button scope; and move the close code to a separate "close connection" button.

Comment: @Khalid jarrah. Why do you mention a button? I hope you don't run it all under a button as this kind of code requires it's own thread and should not run in the UI thread. Do not close any sockets until you are finished.

Comment: my project  make me to make buttons , something really sensitive. dont worry its working . ^_^